# Network Adapter Recieved/Sent bits in C++

Tags: c++

Oh all mighty coding guru's, hear my plea *Bows down*

I am relatively new to C++ and I am trying to make an agent server to sit on a Windows machine and return statistics when polled by a client program. I have already created the UDP communication (For speed) and have figured out how to report back memory, processor utilization and disk space. I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to get the network statistics for a given adapter.

My plan is this: you provide the index number of an interface to the program, and it spits out the network bits per second both received and sent. This way I can monitor the network utilization and see if an adapter is getting slammed (Similar to what you see in Task Manager).

Reason for this is SNMP on Windows only has 32bit integers which is fine if your network bandwidth is 100mbps but when it is gigabit, the counter wraps around faster than I can poll it, thus giving unreliable results.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Hard to really comment without seeing code for the API calls you're using.  But have you read this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/overview-of-ndis-network-interfaces -- specifically, the [NDIS_INTERFACE_INFORMATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ifdef/ns-ifdef-ndis_interface_information) structure appears to support 64-bit counters.

Comment: Have a look at [`GetIfEntry()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getifentry) and related functions

Comment: I have been looking at GetIfEntry2 which looks like it may have what I need (Possibly): TransmitLinkSpeed; ReceiveLinkSpeed; Here is the example code I am tweaking and trying to work out but I am getting "'GetIfEntry2' was not declared in this scope", I am using Code::Blocks as my ide: https://pastebin.com/hKFxtZNY

Comment: Scratch that, got it working through Visual Studio. Although the two things I listed only show max speed. Is there anything that shows current speed?

Comment: Please, if you found a solution create an answer to your question. If you have a new question please create a new question post.

Comment: Ok, after a bit more digging, I have found In/OutOctets. They are numbers that keep going up until they wrap around. From my research, 1 octet == 1 bit. So if I take a reading of the InOctets then sleep for half a second then take another reading, I can delta the two and find out the rate of rise. I just be going stir crazy though and barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @chris-p-tech "*From my research, 1 octet == 1 bit*" - look again. 1 octet (aka byte) is 8 bits. "Octet" literally means "a group of 8"

Comment: Doh! Fat fingered it. That is what I meant to say. Egg on my face

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.